# Powershell Hashtable: Cannot convert value "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes"

Tags: powershell, hashtable, lookup-tables

I am trying to assign new IP addresses to newly deployed VMs using the below script

```ps
    $newVmList = @(
        @{"Name" = "TESTVM21"; "NetworkName" = "LS_10.123.16.0/22"; "IPAddress" = "10.123.19.250"; "PrefixLength" = "22"; "DefaultGateway" = "10.123.16.1"; "IfAlias" = "Ethernet0"; "IPFamily" = "IPv4"; "DNS" = "10.163.4.14, 10.163.4.15";}
        @{"Name" = "TESTVM31"; "NetworkName" = "LS_10.123.16.0/22"; "IPAddress" = "10.123.19.251"; "PrefixLength" = "22"; "DefaultGateway" = "10.123.16.1"; "IfAlias" = "Ethernet0"; "IPFamily" = "IPv4"; "DNS" = "10.163.4.14, 10.163.4.15";}
    )
    $setIP = "New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias ""$vm.IfAlias"" -AddressFamily ""$vm.IPFamily"" -IPAddress ""$vm.IPAddress"" -PrefixLength ""$vm.PrefixLength"" -DefaultGateway ""$vm.DefaultGateway"""
    $setDNS = "Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias ""$vm.IfAlias"" -ServerAddresses ""$vm.DNS"""
    
    Foreach($VM in $newVmList) { 
        Invoke-VMScript -VM $VM.Name -GuestCredential $GuestAccount -ScriptText $setIP
        Invoke-VMScript -VM $VM.Name -GuestCredential $GuestAccount -ScriptText $setDNS
    }
```

But there appears to be a problem with my script using a String as input type for Parameter. I looked at a couple of threads but I haven't been able to modify my script with solutions provided. Could someone help me fix it?

```ps
ScriptOutput
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  New-NetIPAddress : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter
|  'AddressFamily'. Cannot convert value "System.Collections.Hashtable.IPFamily"
|  to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.NetIPAddress.Address
|  Family". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name
|  System.Collections.Hashtable.IPFamily to a valid enumerator name.  Specify one
|  of the following enumerator names and try again: IPv4, IPv6"
|  At line:1 char:91
|  + ... -AddressFamily "System.Collections.Hashtable.IPFamily" -IPAddress
|  "System.Collec ...
|  +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-NetIPAddress], ParameterBi
|     ndingArgumentTransformationException
|      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,New-NetIPAd
|     dress
|
|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ScriptOutput
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Set-DnsClientServerAddress : No MSFT_DNSClientServerAddress objects found with
|  property 'InterfaceAlias' equal to 'System.Collections.Hashtable.IfAlias'.
|  Verify the value of the property and retry.
|  At line:1 char:4
|  + & {Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias
|  "System.Collections.Hashtable.IfAl ...
|  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|  ~~~
|      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.Collections.Hashtable.If
|     Alias:String) [Set-DnsClientServerAddress], CimJobException
|      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_InterfaceAlias,Set-D
|     nsClientServerAddress
|
|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I've moved `$setIP` and `$setDNS` inside the Foreach block but that did not make a difference. I suspect something is related to this - `Error: "Unable to match the identifier name System.Collections.Hashtable.IPFamily to a valid enumerator name.  Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again: IPv4, IPv6"` although `$VM.IPFamily` has a value.

Comment: Thank you @CFou. You syntax worked. I don't know how to mark your comment as `Answer`

Comment: @CFou: Kindly post the same as answer.. and Let joso mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done :), you can mark it now :) glad it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables should be defined inside the `ForEach` Block (`$vm` does not exists before), not before. Move your `$setIP` and `$setDNS` declarations just before the first `Invoke-VMSCript`.

And use this syntax :

```
$setIP = "New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias $($vm.IfAlias) -AddressFamily $($vm.IPFamily) -IPAddress $($vm.IPAddress) -PrefixLength $($vm.PrefixLength) -DefaultGateway $($vm.DefaultGateway)" 
$setDNS = "Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias $($vm.IfAlias) -ServerAddresses $($vm.DNS)"
```

So, you should have this :

```
$newVmList = @(
   @{"Name" = "TESTVM21"; "NetworkName" = "LS_10.123.16.0/22"; "IPAddress" = "10.123.19.250"; "PrefixLength" = "22"; "DefaultGateway" = "10.123.16.1"; "IfAlias" = "Ethernet0"; "IPFamily" = "IPv4"; "DNS" = "10.163.4.14, 10.163.4.15";}
   @{"Name" = "TESTVM31"; "NetworkName" = "LS_10.123.16.0/22"; "IPAddress" = "10.123.19.251"; "PrefixLength" = "22"; "DefaultGateway" = "10.123.16.1"; "IfAlias" = "Ethernet0"; "IPFamily" = "IPv4"; "DNS" = "10.163.4.14, 10.163.4.15";}
)
    
Foreach($VM in $newVmList) { 
   $setIP = "New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias $($vm.IfAlias) -AddressFamily $($vm.IPFamily) -IPAddress $($vm.IPAddress) -PrefixLength $($vm.PrefixLength) -DefaultGateway $($vm.DefaultGateway)" 
   $setDNS = "Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias $($vm.IfAlias) -ServerAddresses $($vm.DNS)"
   Invoke-VMScript -VM $VM.Name -GuestCredential $GuestAccount -ScriptText $setIP
   Invoke-VMScript -VM $VM.Name -GuestCredential $GuestAccount -ScriptText $setDNS
}
```